# Power BI Python Chart. Error when using loc

Tags: python, filtering, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I copied a piece of code that is working on vscode to create a chart on power bi. I've attached the first part of the code below.
I'm trying to filter the dataset (called: dataset) and extract a specific row by filtering the name and year columns.

In this example the name of the player is : 'E. Hazard'.
And year is : 2018

An example of the output: [77.0, 78.0, 85.0, 82.0, 89.0, 61.0, 86.0, 82.0, 81.0, 88.0]

Despite this working on vscode I keep receiving the error:
ValueError: 0 is not in range
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
KeyError: 0

I believe the error is from the loc but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
radar_data = dataset.copy()

radar_data = radar_data.fillna(0)

player = radar_data[radar_data["Name"] == 'E. Hazard']
player = player[player['Year'] == 2018].reset_index()
player = player[['Crossing',
  'Finishing',
  'ShortPassing',
  'Volleys',
  'Dribbling',
  'HeadingAccuracy',
  'Acceleration',
  'SprintSpeed',
  'LongPassing',
  'BallControl'
]]

player = player.loc[0]
player = list(player)
```

```
    Feedback Type:
    Frown (Error)
    
    Timestamp:
    2022-12-15T04:32:14.9588500Z
    
    Local Time:
    2022-12-14T23:32:14.9588500-05:00
    
    Session ID:
    b6f7d653-06b4-4384-9701-ac926ca0ab17
    
    Release:
    December 2022
    
    Product Version:
    2.112.603.0 (22.12) (x64)
    
    Error Message:
    Python script error.
    ValueError: 0 is not in range
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError: 0
    
    
    Stack Trace:
    Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptHandlerException: Python script error.
    ValueError: 0 is not in range
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError: 0
     ---> Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException: Python script error.
    ValueError: 0 is not in range
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError: 0
    
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.PythonScriptWrapper.RunScript(String originalScript, Int32 timeoutMs)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Python.PythonScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Python.PythonScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.RunInternal(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.Run(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.TransformDataShapeResult(QueryCommand transformCommand, SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand command, Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ExecuteDataQuery(IQueryResultDataWriter queryResultDataWriter, EngineDataModel engineDataModel, DataQuery query, Int32 queryId, ServiceErrorStatusCode& serviceErrorStatusCode, CancellationToken cancelToken)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteSemanticQueryCommands(IQueryResultsWriter queryResultsWriter, IList`1 queries, HashSet`1 pendingQueriesToCancel, EngineDataModel engineDataModel)
    
    Invocation Stack Trace:
       at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
       at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.ErrorHostService.GetErrorDetails(ShowErrorDialogArgs args)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.ErrorHostService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ShowErrorDialogCore>b__0()
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.AllowModalDialogs(Action action)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise>b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise[T](Func`1 func, IPromiseStore promiseStore, Int64 promiseHandle)
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.WebView2.WebView2Interop.InvokeCs(InteropCall call)
       at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
       at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WindowManager.ShowModal[T](T dialog, Func`1 showModalFunction)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<Main>b__3()
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<HandleExceptionsWithNestedTasks>b__0()
       at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
       at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
    
    
    OS Version:
    Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0 (x64 en-US)
    
    CLR Version:
    4.8 or later [Release Number = 528372]
    
    Peak Virtual Memory:
    70.1 GB
    
    Private Memory:
    587 MB
    
    Peak Working Set:
    810 MB
    
    IE Version:
    11.789.19041.0
    
    User ID:
    d6c92559-82c4-4835-a6da-c07f1161719e
    
    Workbook Package Info:
    1* - en-GB, Query Groups: 0, fastCombine: Disabled, runBackgroundAnalysis: False.
    
    Telemetry Enabled:
    True
    
    Snapshot Trace Logs:
    C:\Users\Nazar\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\FrownSnapShot9ddefb1a-8e4d-4ca3-9a82-e325f6fd5fa4.zip
    
    Model Default Mode:
    Import
    
    Model Version:
    PowerBI_V3
    
    Performance Trace Logs:
    C:\Users\Nazar\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\PerformanceTraces.zip
    
    Enabled Preview Features:
    PBI_enableWebView2
    PBI_sparklines
    PBI_scorecardVisual
    PBI_fieldParametersSuperSwitch
    PBI_horizontalFusion
    
    Disabled Preview Features:
    PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled
    PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled
    PBI_qnaLiveConnect
    PBI_azureMapVisual
    PBI_compositeModelsOverAS
    PBI_b2bExternalDatasetSharing
    PBI_enhancedTooltips
    PQ_WebView2Connector
    PBI_NlToDax
    PBI_optimizeTabRibbon
    PBI_relationshipEditPane
    
    Disabled DirectQuery Options:
    TreatHanaAsRelationalSource
    
    Cloud:
    GlobalCloud
    
    DPI Scale:
    125%
    
    Supported Services:
    Power BI
    
    Formulas:
    
    
    section Section1;
    
    shared #"All_players (2)" = let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Python\All Files\Projects\Football\Kaggle Fifa Ratings\Ratings\fifa_rating_dataset.xlsx"), null, true),
        All_players_Sheet = Source{[Item="All_players",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(All_players_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Club", type text}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Overall", Int64.Type}, {"transfer", type any}, {"T-From", type any}, {"T-To", type any}, {"percentage_change", type any}, {"rating_change", type any}})
    in
        #"Changed Type";
    
    shared #"Club_rating_change (2)" = let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Python\All Files\Projects\Football\Kaggle Fifa Ratings\Ratings\fifa_rating_dataset.xlsx"), null, true),
        Club_rating_change_Sheet = Source{[Item="Club_rating_change",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Club_rating_change_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Club", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"average_rating", type number}, {"club_average_rating_percentage_change", type number}})
    in
        #"Changed Type";
    
    shared main_df = let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Python\All Files\Projects\Football\Kaggle Fifa Ratings\Ratings\fifa_rating_dataset.xlsx"), null, true),
        main_df_Sheet = Source{[Item="main_df",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(main_df_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Age", Int64.Type}, {"Photo", type text}, {"Nationality", type text}, {"Flag", type any}, {"Overall", Int64.Type}, {"Potential", Int64.Type}, {"Club", type text}, {"Club Logo", type any}, {"Value", type text}, {"Wage", type text}, {"Special", Int64.Type}, {"Preferred Foot", type text}, {"International Reputation", Int64.Type}, {"Weak Foot", Int64.Type}, {"Skill Moves", Int64.Type}, {"Work Rate", type text}, {"Body Type", type text}, {"Real Face", type text}, {"Position", type text}, {"Jersey Number", Int64.Type}, {"Joined", type date}, {"Loaned From", type text}, {"Contract Valid Until", type text}, {"Height", type text}, {"Weight", type text}, {"Crossing", Int64.Type}, {"Finishing", Int64.Type}, {"HeadingAccuracy", Int64.Type}, {"ShortPassing", Int64.Type}, {"Volleys", Int64.Type}, {"Dribbling", Int64.Type}, {"Curve", Int64.Type}, {"FKAccuracy", Int64.Type}, {"LongPassing", Int64.Type}, {"BallControl", Int64.Type}, {"Acceleration", Int64.Type}, {"SprintSpeed", Int64.Type}, {"Agility", Int64.Type}, {"Reactions", Int64.Type}, {"Balance", Int64.Type}, {"ShotPower", Int64.Type}, {"Jumping", Int64.Type}, {"Stamina", Int64.Type}, {"Strength", Int64.Type}, {"LongShots", Int64.Type}, {"Aggression", Int64.Type}, {"Interceptions", Int64.Type}, {"Positioning", Int64.Type}, {"Vision", Int64.Type}, {"Penalties", Int64.Type}, {"Composure", Int64.Type}, {"Marking", Int64.Type}, {"StandingTackle", Int64.Type}, {"SlidingTackle", Int64.Type}, {"GKDiving", Int64.Type}, {"GKHandling", Int64.Type}, {"GKKicking", Int64.Type}, {"GKPositioning", Int64.Type}, {"GKReflexes", Int64.Type}, {"Best Position", type text}, {"Best Overall Rating", Int64.Type}, {"Release Clause", type text}, {"DefensiveAwareness", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}})
    in
        #"Changed Type";
    
    shared #"percentage_change_players_moved (2)" = let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Python\All Files\Projects\Football\Kaggle Fifa Ratings\Ratings\fifa_rating_dataset.xlsx"), null, true),
        percentage_change_players_moved_Sheet = Source{[Item="percentage_change_players_moved",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(percentage_change_players_moved_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Club", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"percentage_change", type number}})
    in
        #"Changed Type";
    
    shared #"chelsea_players (2)" = let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Python\All Files\Projects\Football\Kaggle Fifa Ratings\Ratings\fifa_rating_dataset.xlsx"), null, true),
        chelsea_players_Sheet = Source{[Item="chelsea_players",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(chelsea_players_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Club", type text}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Overall", Int64.Type}, {"transfer", type text}, {"T-From", type text}, {"T-To", type text}, {"percentage_change", type number}, {"rating_change", Int64.Type}, {"Num_of_years_before_joining_chelsea", Int64.Type}})
    in
        #"Changed Type";
```

Comment: Did you solve it? Because I'm having the same issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, I could't! Please let me know if you did.